# Break out of parent function?

Tags: c#, function, return

```
public static void CacheUncachedMessageIDs(List<int> messageIDs)
{
    var uncachedRecordIDs = LocalCacheController.GetUncachedRecordIDs<PrivateMessage>(messageIDs);
    if (!uncachedRecordIDs.Any()) return;

    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
         .....
    }
}
```

The above method is repeated regularly throughout the project (except with different generics passed in).  I'm looking to avoid repeated usages of the `if (!uncachedRecordIDs.Any()) return;` lines.

In short, is it possible to make the `LocalCacheController.GetUncachedRecordIDs` return the `CacheUncachedMessageIDs` method?

This will guarantee a new data context is not created unless it needs to be (stops accidentally forgetting to add the return line in the parent method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It is not possible for a nested method to return from parent method.</s> 
You can do some unhandled `Exception` inside `GetUncachedRecordIDs`, that will do the trick, but it is **not supposed** to do this, so it creates confusion. Moreover, it is very slow.

Another **not suggested** mechanic is to use some `goto` magic. This also generates confusion because `goto` allows unexpected behaviour in program execution flow.

Your **best bet** would be to return a `Result` object with simple `bool HasUncachedRecordIDs` field and then check it. If it passes, then return. This solution solves the problem of calling a method, which is `Any()` in this case.

```
var uncachedRecordIDsResult = LocalCacheController.GetUncachedRecordIDs<PrivateMessage>(messageIDs);
if(uncachedRecordIDsResult.HasUncachedRecordIDs) return;
```

My reasoning for lack of this feature in the language is that calling `GetUncachedRecordIDs` in basically **any** function would unexpectedly end that parent function, without warning. Also, it would intertwine closely both functions, and best programming practices involve loose coupling of classes and methods.

Comment: Thanks, think you're right and returning an object is the way to go!

Comment: If you're resorted to check something on the result anyway I would keep the code as-is as it makes it clearer in the method you want to return from what the criteria are. In other words, you haven't really saved any code by doing `if (uncachedRecordIDs.ShouldReturn) return;` vs. `if (!uncachedRecordIDs.Any()) return;`.

Comment: To be clear: The current code reads to me as "if there aren't any uncached records then return", this is much easier to me to read than "if I should return then return".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 
I agree that `ShouldReturn` was rubbish, changed it into `HasUncachedRecordIDs`. It is too explicit I think, but should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an `Action` to your `GetUncachedRecordIDs` method which you only invoke if you need to. Rough sketch of the idea:

```
// LocalCacheController
void GetUncachedRecordIDs<T>(List<int> messageIDs, Action<List<int>> action)
{
    // ...
    if (!cached) {
        action(recordIds);
    }
}

// ...

public static void CacheUncachedMessageIDs(List<int> messageIDs)
{
    LocalCacheController.GetUncachedRecordIDs<PrivateMessage>(messageIDs, uncachedRecordIDs => {
        using (var db = new DBContext())
        {
             // ...
        }
    });
```

}